# Stream OpenCV cv::Mat image to website (html5 page)

Tags: c++, opencv, streaming

I have c++ code running on a raspberry pi using OpenCV to process the camera input (form and color detection). Here is the thread where i capture my images from my pi cam:

(variables names are in french, sorry about that)

```
    Mat imgOriginal;
    VideoCapture camera;
    int largeur = camPartage->getLargeur();
    int hauteur = camPartage->getHauteur();

    camera.open(0);
    if ( !camera.isOpened() )
    {
        screen->dispStr(10,1,"Cannot open the web cam");
    }
    else
    {
        screen->dispStr(10,1,"Open the web cam");

        camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,largeur);  
        camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,hauteur); 
        camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,30);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if(largeur != camPartage->getLargeur() || hauteur != camPartage->getHauteur())
        {
            largeur = camPartage->getLargeur();
            hauteur = camPartage->getHauteur();
            camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,largeur);
            camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,hauteur);
        }

        camera.grab();
        camera.retrieve(imgOriginal);

        camPartage->setImageCam(imgOriginal); //shared object

        if(thread.destruction == DESTRUCTION_SYNCHRONE)
        {
            pthread_testcancel();
        }

        usleep(20000);
    }
```

Now, i want to stream those images to my website hosted on another raspberry pi. I have looked into gstreamer, ffmpeg and sockets but i didn't find any good example in c++ that worked for me. Im trying to get the lowest latency possible.

Some people suggested to use raspistill but i can't open the camera in another program since its already open by OpenCV.

If you need more information let me know, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stream your camera images from a RPi on the network, There are many approaches to do that, based on your needs.

One approach is to use high-level applications like [MJPG streamer](https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer), [RPi IP Camera](http://ronnyvdbr.github.io/RaspberryIPCamera/), etc.

Another approach is, you can stream camera images throw a network (by RTP, UDP, etc) with GStreamer, FFmpeg, [Raspistill](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspistill.md), etc. With this approach, you need to have a receiver app to get streams (e.g FFmpeg).

There is also another approach which you already stated in your question and that is directly accessing the camera and capture images then transfer them manually throw network. With this approach, you have more freedom to modify the design (like adding your own compression, encryption, etc) but you should take care of the network protocol by yourself.
In your example, you can transfer each frame in network with a simple TCP/IP socket or you can build up a simple web server. It is obvious that you can't access the cam with two apps at the same time. You can use [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) to create multiple camera interfaces and access them by multiple apps but it won't solve your problem.

There are good projects like [rpi-webrtc-streamer](https://github.com/kclyu/rpi-webrtc-streamer) and [streameye](https://github.com/ccrisan/streameye) which uses low-level protocols to transfer images.